# How to make quads after applying bevel modifier with non destructive way

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I would like to use non destructive beveling with modifier, but also want to keep quads polygons for good topology. I used outer arch for beveling to have this nice arch, but it creates an 6-gon.

[image]

I tried to use triangulate modifier in order to keep all this non destructive, but it creates 3-gons while I would like only quads.

[image]

Here is an example of a good mesh topology made by manual editing (no modifier) - the screen shot was taken from "Blender Beginner Modelling Chair Tutorial - part 2" by Andrew Price.

[image]

Comment: Set the angle to 0 on the Bevel modifier, so it will bevel the flat edges too.

Comment: How it is going to solve the problem of the n-gon ?